# Cannot get the proper Datetime to the primeng table from mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, angular, typescript

I am working on a small project in which, when a button is clicked the username and datetime should be inserted into MySQL database.it works as desired.

But when I try to display the username and datetime in angular primeng table the datetime changes to GMT format. I"m clueless. how to fix this?.

```
 load=function(){
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/load').subscribe(data => {
  // Read the result field from the JSON response.
  this.rows=JSON.parse(data["_body"]);

}); }    <p-dataTable [value]="rows">
    <p-column field="id" header="ID"></p-column>
    <p-column field="username" header="Name of Person who sent HI"></p-column>
    <p-column field="datetime" header="Datetime"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

This is the code in typescript file and I use this row's value in primeng table to display the values.
p-dataTable is used in HTML file.

```
server.route({
method: 'GET',
path: '/load',
handler: function(request, reply) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM hi ", function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return reply(JSON.stringify(results));
    });

}});
```

This is the code in server.js in which the the table is retrieved in which the datetime column present

Comment: Edit your question to show the schema of your table. Also, where is the code to display the datetime value? It should format the datetime to the format you want to appear in the results.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.rows[0])` ?